# How to install Wordpress on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, installation

So I've been trying to install wordpress on my linux server and have been unsuccessful. I've been following a guide (Link at the bottom)

Now in the section where you create the wordpress database here where the instructions are:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE wp_myblog; 
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_myblog.* TO 'your_username_here'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_chosen_password_here'; mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
mysql> EXIT;
```

am I suppose to replace 'your_usernamehere@localhost' with the username and IP address of my server (as in user@123434243 (Whatever the IP address of my server is))

And also for changing the wp-config.php file here:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here'); /** MySQL database username */ define('DB_USER', 'username_here'); /** MySQL database password */ define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here'); /** MySQL hostname */ define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */ define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */ define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Do I replace the highlighted blue sections with my own values? I'm so confused what to replace and what to copy verbatim, and then when I put my IP address on the browser it just shows 'page isn't working, unable to handle request'

Please help, I've been trying to install this for hours and it hasn't worked

https://www.tecmint.com/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-lamp/

Answer (score 0):

The guide you posted suggests the DB Name should be changed too.  That's confusing, because 'localhost' is usually the name of a database-SERVER, not a database.

The guide indicates the following should be changed:

STEP 5

- database_name (it uses WP_myblog)
- databaseuser
- databaseuser_password

It then also says "database host" should be changed.

Have a look at this setup guide from the ubuntu site:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview

It does not appear to require the database host (which is almost always going to be the same as the WP Host server)

Comment: It's not on a local server. So do I replace values on both examples I gave or just one?

Comment: Is it on the same server you are installing WP to?

If it is, then it is "local" - If not, then you would need the database-server address (but it is almost always local)

Comment: Found what appears a more straight forward guide - Try that.